# R data.table - Apply a function, which uses a subset of all other rows, to each row

Tags: r, data.table, non-equi-join

I have a dataset with data about subscriptions. For each subscription there is the subscriber, the type of subscription, the subscription issue date, the subscription start date, and the subscription end date. One subscriber might have multiple subscriptions of the same type at the same time (i.e. the date intervals might be overlapping).

For each subscription I need to calculate the number of subscription days that the specific subscriber had for that specific type of subscription during the 1826 days (approximately 5 years) before the issue date of that specific subscription.

I wrote a functioning, but slow code. I tried speeding it up by using apply/mapply and purrr, but didn't get that to work. Also I wasn't sure how to re-write it as a vectorized function.

How could I speed up the following working code?

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

# create example data
df <-
  data.frame(
    SUBSCRIBER = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"),
    SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE = c("X", "X", "X", "X", "Z", "Z", "X", "X", "X"),
    SUBSCRIPTION_ISSUE = c(
      "2021-12-31",
      "2022-01-02",
      "2022-12-21",
      "2023-01-01",
      "2025-01-01",
      "2025-01-03",
      "2023-01-01",
      "2025-01-01",
      "2025-01-03"
    ),
    SUBSCRIPTION_START = c(
      "2022-01-01",
      "2022-01-03",
      "2023-01-01",
      "2023-01-03",
      "2025-01-01",
      "2025-01-03",
      "2023-01-03",
      "2025-01-01",
      "2025-01-03"
    ),
    SUBSCRIPTION_END = c(
      "2022-01-05",
      "2022-01-07",
      "2023-01-05",
      "2023-01-07",
      "2025-01-05",
      "2025-01-07",
      "2023-01-07",
      "2025-01-05",
      "2025-01-07"
    )
  )

# convert date columns to Date format
df$SUBSCRIPTION_ISSUE <- as.Date(df$SUBSCRIPTION_ISSUE)
df$SUBSCRIPTION_START <- as.Date(df$SUBSCRIPTION_START)
df$SUBSCRIPTION_END <- as.Date(df$SUBSCRIPTION_END)

# Convert data frame to data table
dt <- as.data.table(df)


# create a function to calculate the cumulative day count for each subscriber, subscription type, and issue date
calc_cumulative_days <-
  function(dtinput,
           this_SUBSCRIBER,
           this_SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE,
           this_SUBSCRIPTION_ISSUE) {
    # filter the rows within the sliding window
    dtsubset <-
      dtinput[SUBSCRIBER == this_SUBSCRIBER &
                SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE == this_SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE &
                SUBSCRIPTION_START < this_SUBSCRIPTION_ISSUE &
                SUBSCRIPTION_END > this_SUBSCRIPTION_ISSUE - 1826, ]
    dtsubset$days <- 1
    
    # create a data table with all dates within the sliding window
    dates <-
      data.table(date = seq(
        from = this_SUBSCRIPTION_ISSUE[1] - 1,
        length.out = 1826,
        by = "-1 day"
      ))
    
    # convert date variable to class Date
    dates[, date := as.Date(date)] # Not sure whether this row speeds up or slows down
    setkey(dates, date) # Not sure whether this row speeds up or slows down
    
    # join with the dates table to get all dates within the sliding window
    joined <-
      dates[dtsubset, on = .(date >= SUBSCRIPTION_START, date <= SUBSCRIPTION_END)]
    result <- nrow(joined)
    return(result)
  }



# apply the function to each row in the data table
dt[, historic_subscription_days := calc_cumulative_days(dt, SUBSCRIBER, SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE, SUBSCRIPTION_ISSUE), by = seq_len(nrow(dt))]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `outer`:

```
dt[
  , historic_subscription_days := {
    m <- outer(SUBSCRIPTION_END, SUBSCRIPTION_ISSUE - 1, pmin) - 
      outer(SUBSCRIPTION_START, SUBSCRIPTION_ISSUE - 1826, pmax) + 1
    colSums(m*(m > 0))
  }, SUBSCRIBER:SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE
]
dt
#>    SUBSCRIBER SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE SUBSCRIPTION_ISSUE SUBSCRIPTION_START SUBSCRIPTION_END historic_subscription_days
#> 1:          A                 X         2021-12-31         2022-01-01       2022-01-05                          0
#> 2:          A                 X         2022-01-02         2022-01-03       2022-01-07                          1
#> 3:          A                 X         2022-12-21         2023-01-01       2023-01-05                         10
#> 4:          A                 X         2023-01-01         2023-01-03       2023-01-07                         10
#> 5:          A                 Z         2025-01-01         2025-01-01       2025-01-05                          0
#> 6:          A                 Z         2025-01-03         2025-01-03       2025-01-07                          2
#> 7:          B                 X         2023-01-01         2023-01-03       2023-01-07                          0
#> 8:          B                 X         2025-01-01         2025-01-01       2025-01-05                          5
#> 9:          B                 X         2025-01-03         2025-01-03       2025-01-07                          7
```

Benchmarking, the `outer` solution is about 20 times faster on this dataset. As the dataset gets larger, the difference will become even more pronounced.

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  historic_subscription_days = dt[, historic_subscription_days := calc_cumulative_days(dt, SUBSCRIBER, SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE, SUBSCRIPTION_ISSUE), by = seq_len(nrow(dt))],
  outer = dt[
    , historic_subscription_days := {
      m <- outer(SUBSCRIPTION_END, SUBSCRIPTION_ISSUE - 1, pmin) - 
        outer(SUBSCRIPTION_START, SUBSCRIPTION_ISSUE - 1826, pmax) + 1
      colSums(m*(m > 0))
    }, SUBSCRIBER:SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE
  ],
  check = "equal"
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>                        expr       min        lq      mean   median        uq       max neval
#>  historic_subscription_days 17428.601 18243.751 20105.650 19611.80 21045.751 29570.101   100
#>                       outer   888.302   949.301  1094.788  1011.65  1101.802  3360.101   100
```

Comment: Thank you! The formula is indeed logical. How did you come up with this solution?

Comment: I immediately consider `outer` when I see *compare each with everything else*.